# Using Autofac, NCommon, and Fluent NHibernate, call a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate, autofac, ncommon

I'm having a problem trying to use these three libraries in a project.  I understand  and therefore calling stored procedures isn't directly supported in Fluent NHibernate according to their FAQ.  So I defined a simple hbl.xml file with a mapping for my stored procedure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="My.Data.Mappings" assembly="My.Data.Mappings">
    <sql-query name="MyStoredProc" callable="true">
        <query-param name="paramA" type="date" />
        <query-param name="paramB" type="int" />
        <return alias="MyResultClass" class="My.Data.Mappings.MyResultClass, EP.Core.Data.Mappings" />
        exec myStoredProc @paramA = :paramA, @paramB = :paramB
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So now, in my service code, using the NCommon library, I have:

```
using (var scope = new UnitOfWorkScope())
{
    ...
    DontKnowWhereToGetSessionManager.Instance.Session.GetNamedQuery("MyStoredProc").List<MyResultClass();

    ...
}
```

So the only way I can see of getting DontKnowWhereToGetSessionManager is to have Autofac inject it into my service.  But that seems like the wrong way.  Is there a way to get it from the UnitOfWorkScope?  Or should I just inject it with Autofac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current unit of work by using UnitOfWorkScope's CurrentUnitOfWork property.

```
using (var scope = new UnitOfWorkScope())
{
  var session = scope.CurrentUnitOfWork<NHUnitOfwork>().GetSession<MyResultClass>();
  sesion.GetNamedQuery("MyStoredProc").List<MyResultClass>();
}
```